# Is it possible to see the queries that caused an index miss in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

This is my MongoDB server status of my development environment.

```
  db.serverStatus()
{
        "version" : "1.6.5",
        "uptime" : 792725,
        "uptimeEstimate" : 790787,
        "localTime" : "Fri Sep 06 2013 11:05:32 GMT-0400 (EDT)",
        "globalLock" : {
                "totalTime" : 792724778241,
                "lockTime" : 8441722074,
                "ratio" : 0.010648994841225452,
                "currentQueue" : {
                        "total" : 0,
                        "readers" : 0,
                        "writers" : 0
                }
        },
        "mem" : {
                "bits" : 64,
                "resident" : 3729,
                "virtual" : 13764,
                "supported" : true,
                "mapped" : 12443
        },
        "connections" : {
                "current" : 94,
                "available" : 7906
        },
        "extra_info" : {
                "note" : "fields vary by platform",
                "heap_usage_bytes" : 726448,
                "page_faults" : 403439
        },
        "indexCounters" : {
                "btree" : {
                        "accesses" : 1804253,
                        "hits" : 1803993,
                        "misses" : 260,
                        "resets" : 0,
                        "missRatio" : 0.0001441039588128716
                }
        },
        "backgroundFlushing" : {
                "flushes" : 13211,
                "total_ms" : 176124,
                "average_ms" : 13.331617591401105,
                "last_ms" : 9,
                "last_finished" : "Fri Sep 06 2013 11:04:48 GMT-0400 (EDT)"
        },
        "cursors" : {
                "totalOpen" : 0,
                "clientCursors_size" : 0,
                "timedOut" : 8
        },
        "repl" : {
                "ismaster" : true
        },
        "opcounters" : {
                "insert" : 512974,
                "query" : 18735335,
                "update" : 6690119,
                "delete" : 217251,
                "getmore" : 19071,
                "command" : 8616326
        },
        "asserts" : {
                "regular" : 0,
                "warning" : 0,
                "msg" : 0,
                "user" : 69117,
                "rollovers" : 0
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

My question is whether it is possible to see the values where an index miss happened (queries).

I have set up the profiling level to  `db.setProfilingLevel(2)`
collected records from the system.profile collection using mongoexport option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be aware that `indexCounters.btree.misses` does not indicate that a value was not found in an index; it means that an index page was not in memory when the server tried to access it, and so it had to be paged in.

A query that does not find a particular value in an index would simply be a query that does not find a result to satisfy the query.

One way to log "problematic" queries is with the `slowms` option. Any query that takes longer than a given number of milliseconds is then written to the log file.

You specify `slowms` as an optional second argument to db.setProfilingLevel(), see [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#specify-the-threshold-for-slow-operations) for details.